# OpenCV functions errors in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, opencv

I'm try to write application for iOS using openCV. When I'm using code from the examples (for example squares.c) and adopt it to my interface all is good. But when I'm try to add some functions for testing strange errors occurred. For example:

```
const cv::Point* p = &squares[j][0];
int n = (int)squares[j].size();
cv::Mat image = [my_image CVMat];
polylines(image, &p, &n, 1, true, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 8, CV_AA);   //Working good  
cvFloodFill(&c, cvPoint(10, 10), CV_RGB(255, 0, 0)); // Not working
```

Error:
    OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /Users/Aziz/Documents/Projects/opencv_sources/trunk/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the C++ with the C interface.

The part that's working in written in C++. For it, all the headers are included. But the functions that start with cv, like cvFloodFill, come from the C interface or from the legacy module, and you probably did not include them.

My advice is too keep your code in C++. So, write

```
cv::floodFill( c, cv::Point(10,10), cv::Scalar(255,0,0) );
```

And make sure that the variable name `c` is a C++ thing

Comment: After this changes I have — OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in cvFloodFill. Variable c is cv::Mat c = [image CVMat];

Comment: That is much better! You fixed the compile problem, now you can get on to understand OpenCV. Enter docs.opencv.org, search for `floodFill`, read the docs, check the floodFill example that comes with OpenCV and you'll learn how to use it.